# Linear Regression but the Variables have errors

Tags: regression, errors-in-variables

I have received this confusing task:
You have two variables  and , where y is a response variable which can be written as an explicit linear function of . However, the technique used for measuring  is twice as better than that for
measuring  in the sense of error variance, i.e. the variance of the error in  is twice
as small as the variance of error in . The task is to model y as a function of x.

How should I go about doing this? When I used a basic linear regression algorithm on the data, this was the result:
[image]

When I removed the outliers, this was the result:

[image]

The second one looks pretty good, but I think I am missing something. This is supposedly the data that has a "measurement error".
What do you think I should do instead?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression ?

Comment: @seanv507 I thought about it but it gives me a very similar regression line...

Comment: This looks like two separate problems: (1) what to do about possible outliers; (2) how to perform regression that takes into account variance in both `x` and `y`, once you decide which are the valid observations. Don't confuse those problems.

Comment: @EdM For the first problem I removed 95% outliers, and the result you saw above. So I thought this was pretty much resolved. What about the second one? I don't know exactly how to go about it.

Comment: Good search keywords include "errors in variables regression" and "Deming regression."  "Least angle regression" might be useful, too.